# if I am using Material Design which top header bar component should I use?

Tags: interface-design, google-material-design

I am a new designer and I am designing an application for iPhone devices. if I am using Material Design which top header bar component should I use, that one belongs to Material Design or iOS UI?

[image: Material Design]

According to the answers, I tried to redesign it with iOS methods, let me know if it has any problem.

[image: iOS Design]

Comment: Where can I put my designs and get feedback to make it better?

Comment: well, you did state you're designing for iOS, not Android... so Material Design, which is a Google design standard, would NOT apply, whereas Apple's iOS design standards WOULD apply... across the board and for specific elements. Does that help?

To be clearer - why are you trying to apply Google's Material Design standard to an iOS build?

Comment: @GerardFalla material design is a design standard as you mentioned, but it can be applied *anywhere*. Even in iOS apps, or on the web, or on any operating system. It's generally easier using OS defaults though (where that applies), because it's not available everywhere with a couple of lines of code (but requires a lot of work to create it)